# Hilbert scheme of points 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be a smooth projective variety. We consider the Hilbert scheme X_[n] of points on X.
Denote Z the uiversal subscheme in X×X_[n]. We know that Z|*(X×ζ)=ζ, where ζ belongs to 
X*[n]. But does the ideal sheaf I_Z have the same universal property, i.e. I_Z|_(X×ζ)=I_ζ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The point is that the structure sheaf of $Z$  is flat over $X[n]$, so the formation of its sheaf of ideals commutes with base change on $X[n]$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. Could you give the details? 
Why 0→I_Z→O_(X×X_[n])→O_Z→0 restrict to ζ is still exact? 
Why we don't use subsheaves to construct Quot scheme?

Comment: Restricting to $X \times \zeta$ means tensoring with the structure sheaf of $X \times \zeta$; because of the symmetry of the Tor_1, the exact sequence above stays exact. We don't use subsheaves precisely because they don't pull back to subsheaves, so they don't define a functor.